# Spring autowiring message source vs implementing MessageSourceAware interface?

Tags: java, spring

Which option is better ?

I have an interceptor PermissionInterceptor which needs access to message source.

As far as I know it can be done by autowiring message source or implementing MessageSourceAware interface as follows.

```
public class PermissionInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
   private MessageSource messageSource;

   @Autowired
   public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
     this.messageSource = messageSource;
   }
}
```

or

```
public class PermissionInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter implements MessageSourceAware {
   private MessageSource messageSource;

   public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
     this.messageSource = messageSource;
   }
}
```

Which option is better? Any pros and cons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no real big pros/cons.  Generally it is just a matter of preference of the coder.  I would say that if you are going to use `@Autowired` then put the annotation of the field and drop the method.  This makes it a bit more concise, which for me is the benefit of the annotations.

```
public class PermissionInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

   @Autowired
   private MessageSource messageSource;

   ...
}
```

It may also depend whether you use the annotations rather than XML bindings in the rest of your app config.  If you don't use the annotations elsewhere then I would probably avoid doing it in this case for consistencies sake.

Comment: +1 `MessageSourceAware` was the only option pre-Spring 2.5, but `@Autowired` makes it a bit nicer.